# CAShapeLayer. Does the line pass through the point?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift2

I use CAShapeLayer in order to draw a line on the screen. In the method **touchesEnded** I want to check " Does the line pass through the point?". In my code when I press on the any part of the screen the method **contains** returns always true. Perhaps, I have problem in **line.frame = (view?.bounds)!**. How can I fix it? 
 Sorry for my bad English.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first
    let firstPosition = touch?.location(in: self)

    if atPoint(firstPosition!) == lvl1 {

        let firstPositionX = firstPosition?.x
        let firstPositionY = frame.size.height - (firstPosition?.y)!
        view?.layer.addSublayer(line)
        line.lineWidth = 8
        let color = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8078431487, green: 0.02745098062, blue: 0.3333333433, alpha: 1).cgColor
        line.strokeColor = color
        line.fillColor = nil
        line.frame = (view?.bounds)!
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: firstPositionX!, y: firstPositionY))

    }

}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first
    let firstPosition = touch?.location(in: self)

    if atPoint(firstPosition!) == lvl1 {

        let firstPositionX = firstPosition?.x
        let firstPositionY = frame.size.height - (firstPosition?.y)!
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: firstPositionX!, y: firstPositionY))
        line.path = path.cgPath

    }
}


override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if line.contains(screenCenterPoint) {
        print("ok")
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest calculating the distance between a [line segment and a point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) and see if it falls below some value.

Answer (score 7):

## Problem

The method `func contains(_ p: CGPoint) -> Bool` of `CAShapeLayer` returns `true` if the **bounds** of the layer contains the point. ([see documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410857-contains))

So you cannot use this to check if the **line** contains a point.

There is however, another method with the same name in the class `CGPath` that returns whether the specified point is **interior** to the path. But since you only **stroke** your path and you don't **fill** the interior, this method will not give the desired result either.

## Solution

The trick is to create an **outline** of your path using:

```
let outline = path.cgPath.copy(strokingWithWidth: line.lineWidth, lineCap: .butt, lineJoin: .round, miterLimit: 0)
```

And then check if the interior of the outline contains your `screenCenterPoint`

```
if outline.contains(screenCenterPoint) {
    print("ok")
}
```

[image: Stroke vs outline]

## Performance considerations

Since you are checking the containment only when **touches end**, I think that creating an outline of the path does not add too much overhead.

When you want to check the containment in **realtime**, for example inside the `touchesMoved` function, calculating an outline may produce some overhead because this method is called a lot of times per second. Also the longer the path becomes, the longer it will take to calculate the outline.

So in realtime it is better to generate only the outline of the last drawn segment and then check if that outline contains your point.

If you want to reduce overhead seriously, you can write your own containment function. Containment of a point in a straight line is fairly simple and can be reduced to the following formula:

> Given a line from `start` to `end` with `width` and a point `p`
>
> Calculate:
>
> - `dx = start.x - end.x`
> - `dy = start.y - end.y`
> - `a = dy * p.x - dx * p.y + end.x * start.y - end.y * start.x`
> - `b = hypot(dy, dx)`
>
> The line contains point `p` if:
>
> `abs(a/b) < width/2` **and** p is in the bounding box of the line.

Comment: Amazing answer!